# Counting Argument

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to get the number of ways of doing something. I'm obviously doing it wrong because I'm not getting a whole number as the final answer.

The question: *How many pairs of numbers have $\gcd(M,N)=77$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(M,N) = 2310$?*

**What I've done:**

Since $\gcd(M,N)=77=7\times 11$, both $M$ and $N$ are divisible by $7$ and $11$. Since $\mathrm{lcm}(M,N) = 2310 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11$ we can write
\begin{eqnarray*}
M = 7 \times 11 \times A \times B \times C \\ \\
N = 7 \times 11 \times D \times E \times F
\end{eqnarray*}
where $A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$ are to be drawn from the set $\{1,1,1,2,3,5\}$. There are $6!$ of filling the $A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$ places *if order matters*. Once we've filled all of the slots, we can reorder $A,B$ and $C$ in $6$ ways and $D,E$ and $F$ in six ways without changing the value of $M$ and $N$. Moreover, we can interchange the $1$s amongst themselves without changing either of $M$ or $N$. There are $6$ ways of doing this. To get the total number of arrangements, we divide by $6 \times 6 \times 6$. *However*:

$$\frac{6!}{6^3} = \frac{20}{3} \notin \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your counting assumptions are not correct. $M$ and $N$ need to have the form
\begin{align}
M &= 7\times11\times M' \\
N &= 7\times11\times N',
\end{align}
where $M'$ and $N'$ are relatively prime and $\operatorname{lcm}(M',N')=2\times3\times5$. For each of the three prime divisors ($2$, $3$, and $5$) there are two possibilities: the prime can divide $M'$ or $N'$ but *not both*. Hence the total is $2\times2\times2=8$ possibilities.

**Edit**: The answer actually depends on what counts as a pair. I took "pair" to mean "ordered pair", so that, for example, $(385,462)$ and $(462,385)$ would be different.

Comment: I suspect the answer may be $4$ pairs, so you might try to list your $27$ pairs and check whether they are distinct from other pairs and have $\gcd(M,N)=77$

Comment: The prime factors can't divide both. We know that $LCM \times GCD = M \times N$. In this question $LCM/GCD=30=2\times 3 \times 5$. We only have one $2$, one $3$ and one $5$ to be shared out between $M$ and $N$. When $M$ gets a factor of $2$, $N$ can't have one.

Comment: I think that you're still over-estimating the number. Given that $M \le N$, I find four pairs: $(385, 462)$, $(231, 770)$, $(154, 1155)$, and $(77, 2310)$.

Comment: That's fine: I counted your pairs twice. See my edit.